# Bootstrap 5 collapse component's dispose method is not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Does anyone know why bootstrap collapse [method's](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/#methods) dispose method is not working and I am not getting it how it is supposed to work. I used to think that it should break component and remove data as we used to do in jQuery widget case but strangely nothing is happening here.

I am writing a case where I need collapse element in mobile but not in desktop so I am trying to access element's collapsible instance like this.

```
  const collapseInstance = bootstrap.Collapse.getInstance(collapseEL);
```

Here is generated some code where it is even not working after it is clicked and toggled and so `collapseInstance` should exist and dispose should be called when clicking on dispose button which happens but doing nothing.

```js
function disableCollapse() {
    const collapseEL = document.querySelector('.collapse');
    const collapseInstance = bootstrap.Collapse.getInstance(collapseEL);
    collapseInstance.dispose()
}
window.disableCollapse = disableCollapse;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Toggle Collapse
  </a>
  <button type="button" onclick="disableCollapse()" class="btn btn-primary">Dispose</button>

  <div id="collapseExample" class="collapse">
    <div class="card card-body">
      This is the content of the collapse. It will be disposed on desktop view and recreated on mobile view.
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated... Thanks.

Comment: Well for starters, you are not actually _calling_ that function.

Comment: @CBroe What do you mean by that? Do you have demo on how to make this work?

Comment: `onclick="disableCollapse"` - function calls need `()`, you wrote just the function name there.

Comment: Now there is a JS error, so go and continue with fixing that.

Comment: I know there is js error when we click on dispose before clicking on toggle. Ignore that case for now. Do you have any solution?

Comment: When the collapse is open, the _first_ call does run through without any errors. Clicking the Dispose button a second time, then throws that error - so I would conclude, that the `dispose` call was actually successful. The documentation for that method says, _"Destroys an element’s collapse. (Removes stored data on the DOM element)"_ - so I suppose it might simply not do what you hoped for, in the first place.